# Integral with half tan

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the value of

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+\cos t}dt     
$$

I did the substitution with half $\tan$ and I got something like this:

$$
2\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{t^2+3}dt
$$

Replacing it that would be

$$
2\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\arctan\left(\frac{\tan \left(\frac x 2\right)}{\sqrt 3} \right) 
$$

Which gives me 0 but the answer is $1/\sqrt 3$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The $u=\tan(t/2)$ is not applicable directly for $0<t<2\pi$.

Comment: So I can't use this substitution,what can I do?

Comment: Maybe if you flip it, it will get a full tan.

Comment: Also, the answer should be $2\pi/\sqrt{3}$. Please have a look at this site for similar integrals. They occur every week.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by flipping the integral,I'll look for similar ones right now because this is a question that usually appears in this exam

Comment: i was looking at this to learn myself, the exact integral, with working ,is actually on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution - I see what they did, they split the integral over the discontinuity of $tan(\pi / 2)$ - your problem is that $tan(t/2)$ is not defined over all of the interval, hence they split it up at $\pi$ and compute improper integrals

Comment: @Cato I looked at the wiki integral but I don't understand why at the second one it is -infinity.Could you please explain?

Comment: @lola - The second one is -infinity because the limit of tan(x/2) as x tends to pi from above is -infinity  $tan(\pi/2 + \delta) is -ve$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

begin by putting

$$u=\pi-t $$ to avoid the problem of $t=\pi .$

it becomes

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac {du}{2-\cos(u)}$$

then put $$v=\tan(\frac {u}{2}). $$
to get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac {2dv}{1+3v^2} $$

you can finish by

$$w=v\sqrt {3} $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: set $$\cos(t)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$ and $$dt=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du$$